# Loopback js can't read GET request params in the url

Tags: loopbackjs

I have the following code:

```
Addresses.getorderHistory = function(address, baseToken, status, length, cb) {
            console.log("lenght here -> " + length);
            addressService.getorderHistory(address, baseToken, status, length, cb)
                .catch(err => cb(err));
            };

Addresses.remoteMethod('getorderHistory', {
            http: { verb: 'get', path: '/:address/orderHistory' },
            accepts: [
                            { arg: "address", type: "string", required: true },
                            { arg: "base_token", type: "string", required: true, 'http': {source: 'query'} },
                            { arg: "status", type: "string", required: true, 'http': {source: 'query'} },
                            { arg: "length", type: "string", required: true, 'http': {source: 'query'} }
                    ],
            returns: { type: 'object', root: true }
            });
```

When I make a request like this

```
curl http://localhost:3001/<my root>/addresses/<my address>/orderHistory?base_token=<my token>&status=filled&length=100
```

It says

```
Error: status is a required argument
```

I can basically read `address` and `baseToken` values but I can't read `status` and `length`. What am I missing?

Comment: when you log req.body and req.params what would you get?

Comment: Does your base_token contain special characters or perhaps not serialised correctly?